# Stop running tests if setUp raises an exception in Python unittest

Tags: python, testing

I have this test class:

```
class mytest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        os.mkdir(...)
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        shutil.rmtree(...)

    def test_one(self):
        ...

    def test_two(self):
        ...
```

If something fails after `mkdir` has ran when running `setUp` of `test_one`, it will still try to run `setUp` of `test_two`. At this point I'll get an error on `mkdir` because `rmtree` didn't run.

Is there any way to tell Python unittest to stop running the current test if `setUp` fails? I'm **not** looking to stop on a regular test failure.

Comment: it's hacky but you could just catch exceptions in your `setUp` method and fail accordingly

Answer (score 13):

Add a failure call in the setUp method.

```
def setUp(self):
    try:
        somethingThatMightFail()
    except:
        self.fail()
```

Comment: This only aborts each individual test being set up. I am looking for a way for the circumstances of one setup to **abort all other tests** and setups. I think the OP wanted that too, but there's some ambiguity in the question.